# Call to a member function dispatch() on null Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.php on line 562

Tags: magento2

Why do i get this dispatch() on null error from my custom module

**My error stack trace says:**

Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver->execute( ) ..\InvokerDefault.php:73

Vendor\Module\Model\Engine->productUpdate( )    ..\SyncObserver.php:35

**Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php**

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   protected $syncEngineFactory;

   protected $logger;

 function __construct
(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $syncEngineFactory      
)
{   
    $this->syncEngineFactory = $syncEngineFactory;
}

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->syncEngineFactory->saleOrderComplete($observer);
    $this->syncEngineFactory->productUpdate($observer);
    $this->syncEngineFactory->productDelete($observer);
}
```

**etc/events.xml**

```
  <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
```

Comment: Where is the `dispatch()` event which you want to catch?

Comment: In my events.xml i have used as above updated answer

Comment: Was this the event u were specifying @Khoa, or have i missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are wrong when getting the object from the event. In your case, we need to get the product object from the event: `$product = $observer->getProduct()`.

Comment: Yes Khoa, in \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine, in productUpdate() i got the object as : $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

Comment: But still why i get the same error

Comment: Please, check your custom module and methods: `saleOrderComplete`,  `productUpdate` and `productDelete`. Make sure they worked well.

Comment: Currently, i have commented out Sales and productDelete events, wanted to check first if update event is working, but only for this single event, i face this issue..need suggestion

Comment: Try to comment out the `__constructor` also, check only `execute` method. Remove `var/generation` and clear your Magento Cache again.

Comment: Khoa, i changed the model in my constructor, and updated the error here which is bugging me sort of...need your help here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130715/observer-event-argument-1-passed-to-abstractdbload-must-be-an-instance-of-a

Comment: Seem that this question cannot resolve because it is linked to other problems from different parts.

Comment: Ok any idea for the same?