# Observer event Argument 1 passed to AbstractDb::load() must be an instance of \AbstractModel

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

Need some clarity or correction in my Observer class where I'm trying to save the product when it is updated, but I get "*Call to member function `dispatch()` on `null`*"

**Here is my `events.xml`**

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
```

**`Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_queue;

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory
 */
protected $syncEngineFactory;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue $queue
 */
function __construct
(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue $queue
)
{   
    $this->_queue = $queue;
}

public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $this->productUpdate($product);
        return $this;
}

  public function productUpdate($product){
    //Till here the my product gets saved!!!
  }
}
```

Now in my `productUpdate()` has current code custom as:

---

**UPDATED:**

```
public function productUpdate($product)
{
    //$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();   
    $product_id = $product->getId();  //i get the id here

        if(!$product_id) {
            return;
        }
        //Check already record is exists in queue table
        $existingProduct = $this->_queue->load($product_id,'entity_id');   //problem here...
```

^ Here I get:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::load() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel, string given, called in app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php on line 51 and defined in lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php on line 333

```
        $_id = $existingProduct->getId();

        if(empty($_id)) {
            $data = array(
                "product_id" => (int) $product_id
            );

                $this->_queue->setData($data);
                try {
                    $queue_id = $this->_queue->save()->getId();

                    //custom defined log
                    /* $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/productUpdate.log');
                    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                    $logger->addWriter($writer);
                    $logger->info("Queueing: [ ".$product_id." ] new product"); */

                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->log(null, "Sync Queue: error adding product [ ".$product_id." ] in queue");

                }

        } else {
            $logger->info("Sync Queue: Error adding product  [".$product_id." ] in queue");
        }
   }
```

**`Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue.php`**

```
protected function _construct()
{
        $this->_init('tgs_queue','id');
}
```

What's the correct usage of my `load()` 1st argument I get the above error.

Cause i'm already calling the `$this->_queue->load` in Observers constructor.

Please correct me the proper code in the `productUpdate()` function.

I'm trying to save the product id in my custom table upon changing or updating any product details

Answer (score 2):

Change below line in your `Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_queue;

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory
 */
protected $syncEngineFactory;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $queue
 */
function __construct
(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $queue // change here
)
{   
    $this->_queue = $queue;
}
```

Also, change in `productUpdate()`

```
 public function productUpdate($product)
{
    //$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();   
    $product_id = $product->getId();  //i get the id here

        if(!$product_id) {
            return;
        }
        //Check already record is exists in queue table
        $existingProduct = $this->_queue->create()->load($product_id,'entity_id');   //solution here...
```

Comment: I get Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory::load() in my Observer

Comment: Is Queue.php model file located in model directory ?

Comment: Yes inside Model directory

Comment: Is that Model or ResourceModel..? in \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory...

Comment: It's Model @SachinS

Comment: Accept the answer If you find It helpful @SachinS